# How to run Fasttext get_nearest_neighbors() faster?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, gensim, fasttext

I'm trying to extract morphs/similar words in Sinhala language using Fasttext.
But FastText takes a 1 second for 2.64 words. How can I increase the speed without changing the model size?

My code looks like this:

```
import fasttext
fasttext.util.download_model('si', if_exists='ignore')  # Sinhala
ft = fasttext.load_model('cc.si.300.bin')
words_file = open(r'/Datasets/si_words_filtered.txt')
words = words_file.readlines()
words = words[0:300]
synon_dict = dict()
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
for i in tqdm_notebook(range(len(words))):
    word = words[i].strip()
    synon = ft.get_nearest_neighbors(word)[0][1] ### takes a lot of time
    if is_strictly_sinhala_word(synon):
        synon_dict[word] = synon
import json
with open("out.json", "w", encoding='utf8') as f:
    json.dump(synon_dict, f, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a fully accurate `get_nearest_neighbors()`-type of calculation is inherently fairly expensive, requiring a lookup & calculation against *every* word in the set, for each new word.

As it looks like that set of vectors is near or beyond 2GB in size, when just the word-vectors are loaded, that means a scan of 2GB of addressable memory may be the dominant factor in the runtime.

Some things to try that might help:

- Ensure that you have plenty of RAM - if there's any use of 'swap'/virtual-memory, that will make things far slower.
- Avoid all unnecessary comparisons - for example, perform your `is_strictly_sinhala_word()` check *before* the expensive step, so you can skip the costly step if not interested in the results. Also, you could consider shrinking the full set of word-vectors to eliminate those that you are unlikely to want as responses. This might involve throwing out words you know are not of the language-of-interest, or all lower-frequency words. (If you can throw out half the words as possible nearest-neighbors before even trying the `get_nearest_neighbors()`, it will go roughly twice as fast.) More on these options below.
- Try other word-vector libraries, to see if they offer any improvement. For example, the Python Gensim project can load either plain sets of full-word vectors (eg, the `cc.si.300.vec` words-only file) or FastText models (the `.bin` file), and offers a `.most_similar()` function that has some extra options & *might*, in some cases, offer different performance. (Though, the official Facebook Fasttext `.get_nearest_neighbors()` is probably pretty good.)
- Use an "approximate nearest neighbors" library to pre-build an index of the word-vector space that can then offer extra-fast nearest-neighbor lookups - although at some risk of not finding the exact right top-N neighbors. There are many such libraries – see this [benchmarking project](https://github.com/erikbern/ann-benchmarks) that compares over 20 of them. But, adding this step complicates things & the tradeoff of that complexity & the imperfect result may not be worth the effort & time-savings. So, just remember that it's a possibility if your need s large enough & nothing else helps.

With regard to slimming the set of vectors searched:

- The Gensim `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` function, which can load the `.vec` words-only file, has an option `limit` that will only read the specified number of words from the file. It looks like the `.vec` file for your dataset has over 800k words - but if you chose to load only 400k, your `.most_similar()` calculations would go about twice as fast. (And, since such files typically front-load the files with the most-common words, the loss of the far-rarer words may not be a concern.)
- Siilarly, even if you load all the vectors, the Gensim `.most_similar()` function has a `restrict_vocab` option that can limit *searches* to just the 1st words of that count, which could also speed things or helpfully drop obscure words that may be of less interest.
- The `.vec` file may be easier to work with if you wanted to pre-filter the words to, for example, eliminate non-Sinhala words. (Note: the usual `.load_word2vec_format()` text format needs a 1st line that declares the count of words & word-dimensionality, but you may leave that off, then load using the `no_header=True` option, which instead uses 2 full passes over the file to get the count.)